# python convert custom object to json using properties

Tags: python, bottle

In Bottle framework or python in general, is there a way to convert a custom object to json using the properties of the object?
I saw few posts which recommend to write `to_json(self)` kind sort of method on the custom class. Was wondering if there is any automated way of doing the same?

Coming from Java world, was hoping for `Jackson` type of module with `XmlRootElement` annotation (or decorator in python terms). But didn't find any so far.

**UPDATE** I do not want to use `__dict__` elements. Instead want to use properties of my custom class to build the json.

Comment: I suspect you will need to look at some other serialization library ... json can only handle basic types (strings,ints,lists,dicts,etc) ... pickle can handle alot more ... if you need to define custom types and whatnot you will probably need to use YAML (which is kinda gross ... but I think this is similar to what you were asking about in java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a decorator to "mark" the properties that needs to be represented. 
You would still need to write a to_json function, but you will only need to define it once in the base class

Here's a simple example:

```
import json
import inspect

def viewable(fnc):
        '''
            Decorator, mark a function as viewable and gather some metadata in the process

        '''
        def call(*pargs, **kwargs):
                return fnc(*pargs, **kwargs)
        # Mark the function as viewable
        call.is_viewable = True
        return call

class BaseJsonable(object):

    def to_json(self):
        result = {}
        for name, member in inspect.getmembers(self):
            if getattr(member, 'is_viewable', False):
                value = member()
                result[name] = getattr(value, 'to_json', value.__str__)()
        return json.dumps(result)

class Person(BaseJsonable):

    @viewable
    def name(self):
        return self._name


    @viewable
    def surname(self):
        return self._surname

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self._name = name
        self._surname = surname


p = Person('hello', 'world')
print p.to_json()
```

Prints

```
{"surname": "world", "name": "hello"}
```

Comment: Is there any library for that? With comfortable decorator to specify different name in json, default value, etc as other powerful JSON parsers in Java and C#.